# SQL Server return statement

Tags: sql-server

I had this query:

```
SELECT t.price/100 as P 
FROM mytable.user as t 
WHERE t.price = ?;
```

But i want to check if the parameter value is equals Zero before the SELECT to avoid sql error, so i've tried this:

```
IF (CAST(? AS float) = 0) 
BEGIN 
  RETURN 0 
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
  SELECT t.price/100 as P 
  FROM mytable.user as t 
  WHERE t.price = ?
END;
```

But i have this error message(line 3):

> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this
>   context.

Comment: It is a view or procedure? What is a context?

Comment: Why would `t.price = 0` cause a SQL error?

Comment: SELECT t.price/100 as P will cause an error...

Comment: You should be validating parameters before they get to SQL - and in any case a 0 will not throw a sql error, it'll just return no rows.

Comment: Nope. 0/100 is zero.  100/zero would be a different matter, but that's not what you are doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use return 0 instead use select 0 as p. Below is sample.

```
IF (CAST(? AS float) = 0) 
BEGIN 
    select 0 as P
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT t.price/100 as P 
    FROM mytable.user as t 
    WHERE t.price = ?
END;
```